# How to initialize and use a C11 _Atomic variable?

Tags: c, atomic, c11

Is the following code allowed?

```
_Atomic(unsigned int) a = 1;
if (a == 0) {

}
```

The C11 spec (n1570) says at 6.3.2.1p2:

> if the lvalue has atomic type, the value has the non-atomic version of the type of the lvalue.

So this seems to say it's ok.

Comment: Perhaps this question is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668941/c11-grammar-ambiguity-between-atomic-type-specifier-and-qualifier

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.2.4 _Atomic type specifiers_ indicates that your declaration is probably OK.  §6.7.4 _Type qualifiers_ includes an example: `_Atomic volatile int *p;` without the parentheses, so the parentheses are not always necessary.

Comment: Well, it's more the reference to "a", whether that's an ok way to load the atomic value.

Comment: AFAICT, yes — but I've not actually tried it...have you got a C11 compiler to try it on?

Comment: The C11 compiler crashed, hence the question! :)

Answer (score 7):

<strike>No, initialization like that is not ok. You'd have to use `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` to initialize an atomic object. From C11 7.17.2.1:</strike>

> The ATOMIC_VAR_INIT macro expands to a token sequence suitable for
> initializing an atomic object of a type that is
> initialization-compatible with value. An atomic object with automatic
> storage duration that is not explicitly initialized using
> ATOMIC_VAR_INIT is initially in an indeterminate state; however, the
> default (zero) initialization for objects with static or thread-local
> storage duration is guaranteed to produce a valid state.

Otherwise the object would be in a valid state, but "indeterminate" so you wouldn't know which value it has.

The state of this has changed with C17 which removed the requirement to initialize with `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT`. Now doing an initialization as presented in the question is ok and the right way to go.

As someone suggested, another possibility is still to do a dynamic initialization with `atomic_init`, but classic initialization is certainly to be preferred wherever you may.

Comment: Thanks, I shouldn't have include the "= 1", I didn't want people to complain about using uninitialized values! (then I forgot to use the macro)

Comment: And wouldn't `atomic_load` be necessary as well at `a == 0`? C++ always does it through `operator T()`.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰, no, all operators work for atomic variables. They have sequential consistency per default.

Comment: I couldn't find that very clearly in C11, what part describes it?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰, it is 6.2.6.1 p 9

Comment: `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` is deprecated in C17 and slated for removal in a future standard. Use `atomic_init()` instead.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau, no `atomic_init()` is only suboptimal because its dynamic. Plain initialization of atomic objects is ok since C17. See my updated answer.