# Rationale for the C11 _Atomic specifier-vs-qualifier syntax irregularity?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, grammar, atomic, c11

There is a related "what" question here: [C11 grammar ambiguity between _Atomic type specifier and qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668941/c11-grammar-ambiguity-between-atomic-type-specifier-and-qualifier)

What I'm interested is *why*, since the C11 rationale hasn't been published yet, and this seems needlessly complex.

The grammar includes both of these (and resolves the ambiguity in favor of `shift`ing the `(` rather than `reduce` (which would otherwise be in lookahead if followed by a `declarator` or `abstract-declarator`)), reachable from `declaration-specifiers` or `specifier-qualifier-list`:

```
atomic-type-specifier: _Atomic ( type-name )
type-qualifier: _Atomic
```

This leads to the following code:

```
int i1;
int (i2); // valid, same as i1 - usually seen in the context of pointer-to-function or pointer-to-array
int _Atomic a1;
int _Atomic (a2); // invalid
_Atomic (int) a3; // valid, same as a1
```

Thoughts:

- `_Atomic` must not modify an array or function. Barring redundant parentheses around a declarator, this means it would be valid to `#define _Atomic(x) x _Atomic` (if it were legal to `#define` keywords of course).
- When it occurs as a `qualifier`, `_Atomic` is the same syntactical part as `const`, and C programmers are *already* used to putting `const` on the correct side, so it can't be for "ease of use".

Comment: Perhaps this obviously gratuitous introduction of a shift-reduce conflict into otherwise a fairly clean context free  grammar to implement an unneeded feature is to warm us up for http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22//WG14/www/docs/n2137.pdf (Attributes in C), which introduces tens if not hundreds of them. (But hey, at least we'll be more C++-compatible even though we already aren't).

Comment: Seriously, though the redundancies around _Atomic are disappointing. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p3 is redundant too as no qualifiers can be used to apply to whole arrays of functions. Also, why do we also need a bazillion of atomic type aliases -- http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.6p1 ? It'd be nice if the standards explained themselves more. I wish standards were more genius.com for code--public, publicly commentable and with contextual rationalizations that pop up whenever you click on a piece of text.

Comment: For the C++ compatibility thing they could have rather standardized `__typeof`. It's been around forever, it's widely used, and it's been proposed for inclusion in the C standard a long time ago. With __typeof, you could do `#define _Atomic(T) __typeof(T _Atomic)` and it would work with `_Atomic(T) x,y;` to define both x and y as the same type even if `T` is a had a `*` at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rationale is found in [N1485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1485.pdf):

> The `_Atomic` keyword also can also be used in the form `_Atomic(T)`,
>   where `T` is a type, as a type specifier equivalent to `_Atomic T`.
>   Thus, `_Atomic(T) x, y;` declares `x` and `y` with the same type, even
>   if `T` is a pointer type. This allows for trivial C++0x compatibility
>   with a C++ only `_Atomic(T)` macro definition as `atomic<T>`.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: `const int *x, *const y;` == `const int *x; const int *const y;`. The same can be done with the `_Atomic` type qualifier as can be done with the `const` type qualifier, qualifying an atomic pointer type. That's the only plausible reason for the `_Atomic` type qualifier to even exist as far as I'm aware. Otherwise, it's pointlessly redundant.

Comment: As an aside -- at least we know where some of the *casting malloc* garbage comes from [**N1485 pp.4**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1485.pdf)